# How to apply patches in linux

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling

I'm trying to build a kernel using a `make` command. I need to apply patches. All the patches are present in the `SOURCES` directory, and I have extracted `linux-3.8.0` in another directory. I have around 900 patch files. The `*.c` files in the `linux-3.8.0` folder have say names `abc.c` but in their corresponding patch files have the names `001abc.c` in the `SOURCES` directory.

I'm building in Fedora 16. How do I apply patches?

Answer (score 3):

The names of the patch files shouldn't matter. What does (usually) matter is the name of the file to patch, as defined within the first two lines of the patch file itself.

As an example

```
--- /tmp/file.original  2015-10-08 13:02:28.171436259 +0100
+++ /tmp/file   2015-10-08 13:02:31.167408397 +0100
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 This is the file
-This is the original file
+This is the patched version of the file
 This is the file
```

This shows that the file to be patched is `/tmp/file`, and the patch can be applied with `patch -p0 < patch_file`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a patch by doing a `diff` on both folders, and then apply it using the `patch` command. It might be a good idea to have the same file names in both folder, so that it is easier to compare.

You may also use a tool like *meld* to compare the folders, and choose the changes you want to patch/change in the other folder.

Comment: There are already a patch files and i have so many patch files so i can't change the filenames. anyother way?

Comment: What do your patch files look like? Do they only contain changes or are a new version of the older file? It would be nice if you could place a small extract on patch files in your question.